# Python: how to create a class with objects and attributes

Tags: python, function, class, object, attributes

I am new to python. I am learning Object-oriented programming. I would like to create a Class that contains 3 objects and each objects has 5 attributes.

My class is called "Slot", the three objects are called "CPM", "IOM", "MDA" and all three objects have the same five attributes

```
1)SerialNumber 
2)PartNumber
3)Name 
4)Status
5)Type
```

Can you give me an example of how I can do this, and how can I print all 5 attributes WHEN the object is created.

ANY example will be more then appreciated, even if they have different names.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems very basic. You could find the info very easily... 
it sounds like you just want someone working for you.

but let's give it a moment for this time.
if I understand you want 3 instances of a 'Slot' structure. that's it ?
One possibility is:

```
class Slot:
# the '__init__' method is the constructor
# the first argument must be 'self' (as with any method belonging to the class)
#the advantage of giving default values (here 'None') is that you do not have to care the parameter order when calling the method
    def __init__(self,SerialNumber=None,PartNumber=None,
                 Name=None,Status=None,Type=None):
        self.SerialNumber = SerialNumber
        self.PartNumber = PartNumber
        self.Name = Name
        self.Status = Status
        self.Type = Type
        print('Name: ',Name,' ; SerialNumber: ',SerialNumber,
              ' ; PartNumber: ',PartNumber,
              ' ; Status: ',Status,' ; Type: ',Type)

# further in the code, you create the instances of the object Slot
CPM = Slot(Name='CPM', PartNumber='toto', Type='poo')# just to show you can give any parameter in any order
IOM = Slot(Name='IOM')
MDA = Slot(Name='MDA')
# to access the values of instances:
print('CPM name: ',CPM.Name)
print('CPM Type: ', CPM.Type)
CPM.Type = 'paa'
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
class Slot:
    def __init__(*parameters*):
        self.cpm = CPM.CPM(*sub parameters*)
        self.iom = IOM.IOM(*sub parameters*)
        self.mda = MDA.MDA(*sub parameters*)



class CPM:
    def __init__(*sub parameters*):
        self.SerialNumber = *parameter*
        self.PartNumber = *parameter*
        self.Name = *parameter*
        self.Status = *parameter*
        self.Type = *parameter*

        print 'CPM:\n\tSerialNumber: '+self.SerialNumber\n\tPartNumber: '+self.PartNumber\n\tName: '+self.Name\n\tStatus: '+self.Status\n\tType: '+self.Type

class IOM:
    def __init__(*sub parameters*):
        self.SerialNumber = *parameter*
        self.PartNumber = *parameter*
        self.Name = *parameter*
        self.Status = *parameter*
        self.Type = *parameter*

        print 'IOM:\n\tSerialNumber: '+self.SerialNumber\n\tPartNumber: '+self.PartNumber\n\tName: '+self.Name\n\tStatus: '+self.Status\n\tType: '+self.Type

class MDA:
    def __init__(*sub parameters*):
        self.SerialNumber = *parameter*
        self.PartNumber = *parameter*
        self.Name = *parameter*
        self.Status = *parameter*
        self.Type = *parameter*

        print 'MDA:\n\tSerialNumber: '+self.SerialNumber\n\tPartNumber: '+self.PartNumber\n\tName: '+self.Name\n\tStatus: '+self.Status\n\tType: '+self.Type

slot = Slot.Slot(*parameters*)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example should do as you requested. It does not seem wise to me to have a class initializer print out information, so a manual print is executed in the main function. Changing this would be trivial though and is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3


def main():
    cpm = Widget(12, 34, 'A', True, int)
    iom = Widget(56, 78, 'B', False, str)
    mda = Widget(90, 12, 'C', None, bytes)
    s = Slot(cpm, iom, mda)
    print(s)


class Slot:

    def __init__(self, cpm, iom, mda):
        self.cpm = cpm
        self.iom = iom
        self.mda = mda

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{!s}({!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(
            type(self).__name__, self.cpm, self.iom, self.mda)


class Widget:

    def __init__(self, serial_number, part_number, name, status, kind):
        self.serial_number = serial_number
        self.part_number = part_number
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
        self.kind = kind

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{!s}({!r}, {!r}, {!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(type(self).__name__,
                                                           self.serial_number,
                                                           self.part_number,
                                                           self.name,
                                                           self.status,
                                                           self.kind)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```